# Unexpected redux state flushing

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers, state-management

I have a reducer and an initial redux state.

```js
const initialState = {
   arrayValue: ['1', '2']
};

export const reducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'ARRAY_CHANGE': {
      return {
           ...state,
           arrayValue: [...action.payload]
         }
      }
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
```

The reducer works as expected. The strange thing is that `arrayValue` becomes empty when I go to another page and then return to the previous one. I have lots of other reducers and they work absolutely fine.

I checked `dispatch` calls with `'ARRAY_CHANGE'` type through the debugger and I haven't found anything suspicious. It looks like `arrayValue` just becomes empty for no reason. Does anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I checked the state through the Redux Dev-tools. When I go to another page, `arrayValues` becomes an empty array, though there were no `dispatch` calls with the `'ARRAY_CHANGE'` type. Perhaps there are some issues with react-router.

That's how the value being passed to the component.

```js
export default connect(
  state => (
    {arrayValue: state.app.reducer.arrayValue}
  ),
  dispatch => ({
    onChangeArrayValues: arrayValue => 
        dispatch({type: 'ARRAY_CHANGE', payload: arrayValue})
  })
)(MyComponent)
```

**EDIT2:**
OK, I have debugged the code again, and here is what I found.
I have a combined reducer.

```js
const appReducers = combineReducer({
  ui: uiReducer,
  reducer
});


...
const initialState = {
   spinner: false,
}

function uiReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case SPINNER_SHOW: {
         return {...state, spinner: true};
      }
      case SPINNER_HIDE: {
         return {...state, spinner: false};
      }
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
```

These two reducers are separate. But here is what happens on SPINNER_SHOW event. The object structure differs a little bit from what I described. Don't pay attention to this.

[image]

`selectedNodeVerifications` changes the `ARRAY_VALUE`.
[image]

`SPINNER_SHOW` event
[image]

These two events are placed in separate reducers. I have no idea how `SPINNER_SHOW` can affect `selectedNodeVerifications`.

Comment: How is the page rendered? Does it dispatch the `ARRAY_CHANGE` action in any lifecycle functions? Are you examining your redux state via the redux dev tool? or logging it? How are you verifying that it is not what you expect? Is it an empty object, empty array, something else? Does anything else dispatch an `ARRAY_CHANGE` action with empty payload?

Comment: I added some explanations to the question

Comment: Another time I've seen redux state mysteriously change was when a reference to a state value was being mutated elsewhere. Can you also provide the component code in question?

Comment: I added some more explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some sort of solution.

```js
const initialState = {
   arrayValue: ['1', '2'].join(',')
};

export const reducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'ARRAY_CHANGE': {
      return {
           ...state,
           arrayValue: action.payload.join(',')
         }
      }
      default:
         return state;
   }
}

...

export default connect(
  state => (
    {arrayValue: state.app.reducer.arrayValue.split(',')}
  ),
  dispatch => ({
    onChangeArrayValues: arrayValue => 
        dispatch({type: 'ARRAY_CHANGE', payload: arrayValue})
  })
)(MyComponent)
```

It's a dirty approach, but it works. I still don't understand why Redux acts so strangely with array values.

Comment: I guess it's ok that you found a workaround but TBH if this was production code in a pull request I'd not let it be merged. I still suspect something in your UI code is mutating your state reference. Keep following the trail... what does `MyComponent` (or *any* component consuming it) do with `arrayValue` from the `connect` HOC?

Comment: I found the source of the problem. It was caused by the library of components that we use in the project. It provides a custom `CheckboxGroup` that accepts an array of values. The thing is that `onChange` event should return a new array. But instead, it mutates it in place. When I passed a copy of an array as a property (`[...props.values]`), everything started to work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, awesome! State mutations can sometimes be a real bear to debug.